# How do I use lambda expressions to filter DataRows?

Tags: c#, dataset, lambda

How can I search rows in a datatable for a row with Col1="MyValue"

I'm thinking something like

```
Assert.IsTrue(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.
    FindAll(x => x.Col1 == "MyValue" ).Count == 1);
```

But of course that doesn't work!

Comment: Do you want to return the matching rows, or just get a count of how many there are?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) to do this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(
    r => ((string) r["Col1"]) == "MyValue").Count() == 1);
```

Note, you can also do this without the call to Assert:

```
dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(
    r => ((string) r["Col1"]) == "MyValue").Single();
```

If the number of rows does not equal one (hence, the call to `Single`), then an exception will be thrown, and that unhandled exception *should* fail your test case.  Personally, I like the latter, as it has a clearer semantic meaning.

The above can be further whittled down to:

```
dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Single(
    r => ((string) r["Col1"]) == "MyValue");
```

Additionally, you can take advantage of the [`Field` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field.aspx) on the [`DataRowExtensions` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348900.aspx) to simplify type-safe access to the field (as well as providing the extra benefit of converting [`DBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) to null counterparts in .NET):

```
dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Single(
    r => r.Field<string>("Col1") == "MyValue");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `Select` method of the data table to do this, or the Filter Property of the `DefaultDataView` on the table.

For the `Select` method:

```
var rows = dataSet.Tables[0].Select("Col1 = 'MyValue'");
```

For the `DefaultView` Filter:

```
dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView.Fitler = "Col1 = 'MyValue'";
foreach (var drv in dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView)
{
    // Do your processing
}
```

Comment: This may not be what the asker was looking for, but I found it helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Why use lambda and not [select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1(VS.80).aspx)?

```
  DataRow[] foundRow = ( dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Select("Col1 = 'MyValue'");
```

Comment: Should only be 1 equal sign

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
var b=datatable.AsEnumerable.where(p=> p.Field<string>   
("column_name")=="desire_value").CopyToDataTable()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote checks that there's only one row which fulfils your search condition.
If you actually want the rows, drop the `Assert` and `Count`