# Lambdas does not recognize fields of DataTables

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, datatable

I've do this many times in another solutions. But in one of them, It doesn't work. Don't know why.

I want to use `Where()` in some dataTable. So, I do, for example

```
int someId;
DatasetName.DatatableName.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.id == someId);
```

But in this project, it doesn't recognize the lambda `x => x.id == someId`

Why is that? I can't use them. The intelissense, afther the `(` in the `Where` recognize that needs to receive a `Func`, and when I do `x => x.` it doesn't recognize the fields of the DataTable. Why I cant do `x.id` ? I know I can use `Field<>()` (I think that was the name), but I have used the expressions directly a lot of times and I consider them more readables. And in the other solutions does work this.

I have added references of

```
using System.Linq;    
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```

It doesn't compile, and does not recognize any fields of the Datatable.
The project is set for `.Net Framework 3.5`.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are working with a strongly-typed dataset.

The `AsEnumerable()` is probably returning an `IEnumerable<Object>` for some reason. Try adding a cast:

```
DatasetName.DatatableName.AsEnumerable().Cast<MyRowType>().Where(x => x.id == someId);
```

You should also make sure the DataTable properly inherits from `System.Data.TypedTableBase<MyRowType>`.

Comment: Now work. But why does not do an automatic cast? In the other solutions works without the Cast

Comment: Where is the type `MyRowType` from?

Comment: In a dataset, in another Project, that I have referenced with an using

Comment: In the other solutions, also have the datasets in a project, and have them referencied with using, and works

Comment: @ElVieejo Not quite sure why, to be honest. But if the data table inherits from `System.Data.TypedTableBase<MyRowType>` you actually shouldn't need the `AsEnumerable()` call in the first place, as `System.Data.TypedTableBase<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(
r => r["Col1"] == "MyValue")
```

You can use LINQ to DataSets  to do this:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459595/how-do-i-use-lambda-expressions-to-filter-datarows

Comment: I know this, as I know about Field(), but I want to avoid have harcoding name of columns